# В таблицу запросом добавить отсутствующие данные по часам

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в текущую таблицу(DataTable) запросом добавить отсутствующие данные по часам.
Пример:
Текущая таблица:

```
Region  User date hour  pcs
2   131 01.01.2018  1   9
2   131 01.01.2018  2   9
2   131 01.01.2018  4   9
2   131 01.01.2018  6   9
2   262 01.01.2018  1   9
2   262 01.01.2018  4   9
2   262 01.01.2018  1   9
2   131 02.01.2018  2   7
2   131 02.01.2018  4   7
2   131 02.01.2018  6   7
```

Нужно:

```
Region  User date hour  pcs
2   131 01.01.2018  1   9
2   131 01.01.2018  2   9
2   131 01.01.2018  3   0
2   131 01.01.2018  4   9
2   131 01.01.2018  5   0
2   131 01.01.2018  6   9
2   131 01.01.2018  7   0
```

и т.д.

Прим. - Часы (с 1 до 23), месяцы (с 01 по 12)

Comment: Укажите используемую СУБД и её версию. А в общем случае - используйте синтетическую опорную таблицу чисел. И, наверное, не забудьте предусмотреть случай, когда за некую промежуточную дату нет ни одной записи (или хотя бы точно обозначить, что в таком случае делать).

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1)

Comment: Ну тогда в CTE постройте таблицу с числами от 0 до 23, совместите её с `DISTINCT date` и функцией DATEADD сгенерируйте все возможные пары дата-час. К полученному набору прилефтджойните таблицу данных.